vueUse useIntersectionObserver and rootMargin, triggering well before element is within range
I'm really confused what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to implement an infinitescroll that will load new items when the bottom edge of the target element is within 200px of the bottom of the viewport but it triggers almost as soon as I start scrolling
/**
 * Custom composable function for implementing infinite scroll functionality.
 *
 * @param {string} propName - The name of the prop that contains the data to be paginated.
 * @param {HTMLElement|null} landmark - The landmark element to observe for intersection. If null, infinite scroll will not be triggered by intersection.
 * @returns {object} - An object containing the paginated items, methods to load more items and reset items, and a computed property indicating if more items can be loaded.
 */

import { computed, nextTick, ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { router, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue';

export function useInfiniteScroll(propName, landmark = null) {

///

    const observer = useIntersectionObserver(landmark, ([{isIntersecting}], observerElement) => {

        const rect = landmark.value.getBoundingClientRect();
        const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        if (isIntersecting && canLoadMoreItems.value){

            console.log(rect.top, rect.bottom, rect.width, rect.height, viewportHeight, isIntersecting)
            console.log('Root:', observer.root);

            loadMoreItems();
        }
    },
    {

        rootMargin: '0px 0px 200px 0px',
    });

///

}

when it first triggers the log shows:
123 6411 1871 6288 553 true
Root: undefined

Here is the component I am trying to use this composable from:
<script setup>

import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { Head} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import CreatePost from './Partials/CreatePost.vue';
import ShowPost from './Partials/ShowPost.vue';
import { ref, computed  } from 'vue';
import FollowHeader from '@/Pages/Feed/Partials/FollowHeader.vue';
import { useInfiniteScroll } from '@/composables/useInfiniteScroll';

const props = defineProps({
    posts: {
        type: Object,
    },
    users: {
        type: Object,
    },
    featured : {
        type : Object,
        default: null
    },
    follow : {
        type : Object,
        default: null
    },
    user : {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    },
    tag : {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    }

});

//target for infinite scroll
const target = ref(null);
let { items, canLoadMoreItems } = useInfiniteScroll('posts', target)


//is this a featured post? Then open modal
const featuredPost = ref(props.featured);

const showFeatured = computed(() => {
    return featuredPost.value != null;
})

const isFeatured = computed(() => {
    return featuredPost.value != null;
})

//inject trans to pull in title string
const trans = inject('trans')
const title = computed(() => {
    if (props.user){
        return '@' + props.user.username;
    }
    else if (props.tag){
        return '#' + props.tag.tagname
    }

    return trans('feed.feedTitle');
})


</script>

<template>

    <Head :title="title" />

    <AuthenticatedLayout :class="{'blur-sm' : showFeatured}">

        <template #header>
            <div class="flex items-center space-x-3" dusk="feed-header">

                <FollowHeader v-if="user || tag" :user="user" :tag="tag" :follow="follow"/>
                <h2 v-else class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">{{title}}</h2>

            </div>

        </template>


        <div v-show="!user && !tag" class="sm:py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white  shadow sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-2 sm:p-6 text-gray-900">
                        <CreatePost :placeholder="__('feed.postPrompt', {'username': $page.props.auth.user.username})" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="py-2 sm:py-6" ref="target" >
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 sm:space-y-3 space-y-2" >
                <div v-for="post in items" class="bg-white sm:rounded-lg sm:p-3 my-2" dusk="post">
                    <ShowPost :users="users" :post="post" :descendants="post.descendants" :currentDepth="1" @show-post="toggleFeatured(post.id)"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>

Have I somehow got the wrong root set?

Is it possible to share the code of your vue template? Do you have v-intersection-observer attribute or ref="landmark" on your target element?

@nom_unique thanks for replying. I've added the component in now. it's the ref="target" element at the bottom.

When you declare your const observer = useIntersectionObserver(landmark, ....), where does the variable 'landmark' come from? The useIntersectionObserver doc seems to indicate you should pass your target html reference (in your case 'target') as the first parameter. https://vueuse.org/core/useIntersectionObserver/

@nom_unique apologies, I haven't posted my full useInfiniteScroll composable, I've added a little more in now which hopefully makes more sense.

Thank you! Okay so when you pass 'target' here: useInfiniteScroll('posts', target), you are passing the full mutable ref object of 'target', which is not an actual HTML element. You have to access your ref() value with target.value. Try  useInfiniteScroll('posts', target.value) and let me know how it works out.

Also, if you try to access a ref() value on setup(), the value will be Null because the component's DOM tree has not been created yet. You would have to assign { items, canLoadMoreItems } in onMounted hook.

Thanks again for spending time on this, I really appreciate it. Unless I've misread the docs, I'm pretty sure that useInfiniteScroll is expecting a ref no? And I appreciate what you say about how it will be null before the page has rendered, but I thought useInfiniteScroll instantiates a listener which will be checking for an intersection so whilst it's null to begin with, it won't be throughout the lifecycle. https://vueuse.org/core/useInfiniteScroll/#useinfinitescroll

You are right about the documentation! But maybe there's something I am missing... in the code you shared, you are creating your own useInfiniteScroll composable and you don't seem to actually use the useInfiniteScroll from VueUse library. In your component, you could just import { useInfiniteScroll } from '@vueuse/core', then call useInfiniteScroll with your 'target' as first parameter, and callback function as second parameter. In your callback you could put the logic you have in your composable.

While the vueuse implementation is good, I can't find a way to make it work when scrolling 'up' an element. e.g. a chat window will usually have the most recent message at the bottom and the user scrolls up to load more

It's not fully an answer, but I used the new scrollMargin instead rootMargin which worked.
However, I had other issues as I was trying to create an infinite scroll that would accept scrolling up as well as down. e.g. a private message chat where we would usually want to scroll up and have new items added a the top of the feed, not the bottom.
For anyone else who gets stuck with this, this is a modified version that's now working for me:
usage: let { items, canLoadMoreItems, loading } = useInfiniteScroll('posts', infiniteScrollElement,'down', 500)
/**
 * Custom composable function for implementing infinite scroll functionality.
 *
 * @param {string} propName - The name of the prop that contains the data to be paginated.
 * @param {HTMLElement|null} landmark - The element to observe for intersection. If null, infinite scroll will not be triggered by intersection. *** N.B. Must be a scrollable element with a fixed height
 * @param {string|down} scrollDirection - Which direction is user scrolling up/down
 * @param {number|200} triggerDistance - how many pixels from the edge should it trigger.
 * @returns {object} - An object containing the paginated items, methods to load more items and reset items, and a computed property indicating if more items can be loaded.
 */

import { computed, nextTick, ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import { router, usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'


export function useInfiniteScroll(propName, landmark = null, scrollDirection = 'down', triggerDistance = 200) {

    // Store loading state to stop multiple triggers
    const loading = ref(false);

    // Get the value of the prop that contains the data to be paginated.
    const value = () => usePage().props[propName]

    // Create a ref to store all the  paginated items.
    const items = ref(value().data)

    // Watch for changes to prop and update items accordingly.
    // Allows itemsto be added from an external source
    watch(() => value().data, (newValue) => {
        if (!loading.value) {
            items.value = newValue;
        }
    }, { deep: true });

    // Get the initial URL of the page so we can replace the URL after loading more items.
    const initialUrl = usePage().url

    // Computed property to check if more items can be loaded.
    const canLoadMoreItems = computed(() => value().next_page_url !== null)

    // Create the listeners for scoll on the landmark element
    if (landmark != null) {
        nextTick(() => {
            landmark.value.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                    checkPosition();
            });
            landmark.value.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
                    checkPosition();
            });
        });
    }


    // Method to check if the landmark element is in range
    const checkPosition = () => {

        if (loading.value || !canLoadMoreItems.value) {
            return;
        }

        //downward scroll
        if (scrollDirection.toLowerCase() === 'down') {

            const elementScrollBottom = landmark.value.scrollHeight - landmark.value.scrollTop;

            if (elementScrollBottom - window.innerHeight <= triggerDistance) {
                loadMoreItems();
            }
        }

        //upward scroll
        else if (landmark.value.scrollTop <= triggerDistance) {
            loadMoreItems();
        }


    };

    // Method to load more items.
    const loadMoreItems = () => {

        // Set the loading state to true.
        loading.value = true;

        // Load more items using Inertia's get method and append the new items to the existing items.
        router.get(
            value().next_page_url,
            {},
            {
                preserveState: true,
                preserveScroll: true, //only works for downward scroll
                onSuccess: () => {

                    //reset url to initial url
                    window.history.replaceState({}, '', initialUrl)

                    // Capture scroll position
                    const originalScrollPosition = landmark.value.scrollHeight - landmark.value.scrollTop;

                    //add new items to the page
                    items.value = [...items.value, ...value().data]

                    nextTick(() => {

                        // only if its upward scroll reset the scroll position
                        if (scrollDirection.toLowerCase() === 'up') {
                            landmark.value.scrollTop = landmark.value.scrollHeight - originalScrollPosition;
                        }

                    });

                    loading.value = false;
                },
                onError: (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    loading.value = false;
                }
            }
        )
    }


  // Return the items, loadMoreItems method, resetItems method, and canLoadMoreItems computed property.
  return {
    items,
    loadMoreItems,
    resetItems: () => (items.value = value().data),
    canLoadMoreItems,
    loading
  }
}

